# How do I conditionally handle undefined SSI variables using Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, server-side-includes

I want to include a header in a bunch of pages, like so:

`header.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My site</title>
  </head>
```

To enable a page-specific title, I'm trying to use an SSI variable that I set in each page:

`page1.html`:

```
<!--#set var="TITLE" value="first page" -->
<!--#include file="header.html" -->
```

Then I”m modifying `header.html` to use that variable:

```
<title>My site - <!--#echo var="TITLE" --></title>
```

This works fine but, of course, it has the unfortunate effect that, if `TITLE` is not set, the result is:

```
<title>My site - (none)</title>
```

So I'm trying a variety of attempts at conditionally `echo`ing that variable depending on whether it's `none` or not (e.g., `<!--#if expr="TITLE != \(none\)" --> ... <!--#endif-->`) …but nothing seems to work.

Seems like this would be quite a common requirement. Does anyone have a reference to a working solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved it myself. For others' reference:

```
<!--#if expr="${TITLE}!=''" -->
```

is the correct syntax to use. It makes sense that you don't have to check for "(none)" since the undefined text value can be configured; I just didn't realised that occurred after checking the value, not before.

Answer (score 5):

For Apache 2.4 the [expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) have changed:

```
<!--#if expr="-z v('CONTENT_LANGUAGE')"-->
<!--#set var="CONTENT_LANGUAGE" value="en"-->
<!--#endif-->
```

Comment: I came here looking for how to do this in httpd 2.4, since the syntax changed.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this successfully:

```
<!--#if expr="! $CONTENT_LANGUAGE" -->
<!--#set var="CONTENT_LANGUAGE" value="en" -->
<!--#endif -->
```